# set time interval for each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Code: [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/reZRwx)

The demo is working fine on manual scrolling for each div to scrolltop.

What I need is: If I click the `Auto Start` button I want to **Auto scroll 1, Auto scroll 2, ... Auto scroll n** each div to scrolltop.

```
  $(".jumper").on("click", function() { 
            var links = $(this).attr('href');
            var type = links.substring(links.indexOf('#')+1);

          $("body, html").animate({            
               scrollTop: $('#'+type).offset().top  
            }, 1500);   

           });
```

Each div should reach scrolltop and stop, then go to next div scrolltop with same time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
$(".autostart").on("click", function() {
    scrollToElem($("#auto-scroll"));

    var scrollList = $("#auto-scroll").nextAll();
    var current = 0;
    time = setInterval(function() {
      scrollToElem($(scrollList.get(current)));
      current++;
      if (scrollList.length == current) {
        clearInterval(time);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yg30t8vn/)

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code. `.top` of undefined.  You can use links as selector as it contains both idselector + id :

```
$(".jumper").on("click", function() { 
    var links = $(this).attr('href');
    $("body, html").animate({            
        scrollTop: $(links).offset().top  
    }, 1500);   
});
```